# Four downvotes all right next to each other

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, serial-voting

And on unrelated questions no doubt. See [recent activity](https://superuser.com/users/recent/13241?StartDate=2010-05-08&EndDate=2010-05-08). Now will this get caught by that script? Not that I'm worried about the rep, but the answers vote count goes down and that sucks more then the rep.

Comment: We can't see that page.

Comment: That page is currently only available to the 11-13 people with 10k+ rep on Superuser.

Comment: @Chacha: 10k can see everyone's recent activity page?

Comment: @jon no they can't. diamond mods USED to be able to see that, but to prevent .. problems .. only SO team developers can now.

Comment: Sorry, thought that was a deleted post, didn't look at the URL.

Comment: Ah, I thought that page was viewable, my mistake. Anyways, it simply says 4 downvotes on some of my highest voted questions all took place four hours ago on the "yesterday" tab.

Comment: problems indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have concerns about specific downvotes, **and they persist for more than 24-36 hours**, email the address at the bottom of every web page.

Comment: I thought it was simply 24.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it will be caught by the script.

I believe the automated suspicious voting patterns script only looks at down votes between two specific users. While suggestions have been made to have it expanded to down votes to all answers to a single question, I believe too many viable cases for that type of voting were provided.

Comment: I can tell from experience that it doesn't only look at downvotes between two specific users. It will also look at the amount and the relative timespan the subsequent downvotes were taken.

Answer (score 0):

The script kicks if the downvotes are by the same person **and are 5 or more**.

I personally tested this using stackexchange (which I know runs on a slightly different software, but I think we can safely assume that it's highly likely the same limit is used on SO).